# Scroll doesn't work

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

So I have this page, with a background image, that fill up 100 % of the page. The problem is that now my scroll doesn't work, which gives problems on small screens, because the user then not are able to view the content at the bottom of the page.

**CSS CODE:**

```
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#background{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#css{
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top:5%;
left: 1%;
right: 1%;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
line-height:1.5;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<body>
<div>
    <img id="background" src="background.png" />
</div>

<div id="css">
<center>
<img src="logo.png"><br><br>

TEXT LINE 1<br>
TEXT LINE 2<br>
TEXT LINE 3<br>
TEXT LINE 4<br>

</center>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used : `overflow: hidden;` for your `html` and `body`.

So you wont be able to scroll!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from your `html,body` css and add the following

```
body
{
    background: url('background.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `overflow: hidden` setting in your CSS.

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), when using this setting:

> The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

This also implies that you not only not see the scrollbar, as the browser will also not allow you to scroll in that element.

So the answer to your question is: simply remove that CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <img id="background" src="background.png" />
</div>
```

this should go into background. 
in css `body{background: url('background.png') no-repeat;}` and so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background in your CSS not in the html. set a background like this:

```
body{
background: url('background.png');
}
```

You can also use repeat and size options:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I used a background-color as example here:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcDSZ/1/)